# How to upload files to local computer with MAMP?

Tags: php, mamp

I'm trying to upload images to a local server using MAMP.

I post the images using a http-request. that seems to work fine.

This is how I process the files on the backend to reproduce the error:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
    //@todo kolla om några bilder är bifogade, kanske inte behövs.
    $filepath = $file['tmp_name'].'/'.$file['name'];
    echo $filepath . '<br />';

    if(file_exists($filepath)){
        echo 'true <br />';
    }else{
        echo 'false <br />';
    }
}
```

it outputs

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpdaILf2/pdf.pdf
false
```

Ie there is a path and upoad, but nothing in it.

the path

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/
```

exists. I have set the permissions in the php folder, both in finder "Everyone" "read and write" and in the chmod 0777 in the terminal, both to tmp and php-folder. yet, no folder is created inside php and the file is no uploaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have just specified the target directory, next you need to actually "move" the file to the desired place. 
Using move_uploaded_file function.